# Intersection of two quadrics using matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, quadrics

Given any [quadric](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/%7Edhouse/courses/405/notes/quadrics.pdf) can be represented in matrix form, assume I have one quadric $Q_1$ and another quadric $Q_2$. How can I find the equation of the surface that defines intersection of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ (assuming it exists) using matrix algebra?

For example, the intersection of two spheres is an ellipse in 3d space with an equation I can write as $f(x,y,z) = c$. Is it possible to find the intersection of $\mathbf{x}^t Q_1 \mathbf{x} = 0$ and $\mathbf{x}^t Q_2 \mathbf{x} = 0$ without needing to expand these equations and solve algebraically? i.e. working just with the matrices $Q_1$ and $Q_2$?

Comment: The intersection of two quadrics is not a quadric.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks, clarified.

Comment: There is no single equation. It’s given by the two equations $Q_1(x)=0$ and $Q_2(x)=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted, clarified in post.

Comment: Your example is wrong. The intersection is a circle, but it takes two equations, not one. There is, however, no methodology to “solve” in the general case for the quartic curve of intersection. Try Viviani’s curve.